# gpg: overwriting .pdf on encryption => decryption fails

Tags: pdf, gnupg

I use gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.11. to encrypt a file `foo.pdf` via `gpg -c foo.pdf`. The encrypted file is then `foo.pdf.gpg` and, additionally, the original file `foo.pdf` exists. I can then decrypt `foo.pdf.gpg` via `gpg foo.pdf.gpg` as expected. However, if I use `gpg -o foo.pdf -c foo.pdf` and choose to overwrite the existing file on encryption, then use `gpg foo.pdf` to decrypt the encrypted file, and finally choose to overwrite the existing file `foo.pdf` (again), the file is still protected and can't be viewed.

I then tried to execute `gpg foo.pdf` again (I thought decrypting failed the first time, that's why I tried it again). Now the file seems to be corrupted: `gpg: [don't know]: 1st length byte missing`. Any ideas? Is it generally not a good idea to overwrite the files? I expected to obtain one file `foo.pdf.gpg` after encryption (with the original file `foo.pdf` being removed automatically).

Comment: Maybe encrypt to a temp file, delete the original and rename? Does sound like a bug, though. I'd expect GNU would maintain a buglist somewhere - maybe add it to their tracker, and try it on another machine/platform to make sure.

Comment: I tried encrypting it (so obtaining `foo.pdf.gpg`). When decrypting again, it asked me if I want to overwrite the original still-existing non-encrypted file `foo.pdf`. I chose `y` and the file was overwritten. But this time, it could be opened.

Comment: Hmm, so the issue is intermittent? `:(`

Comment: No, it's permanent. It's just that I only overwrote the file on *decryption* (not on *encryption). Finally, I believe the overwrite feature shouldn't be used anyways. Emacs (my editor) can open `.gpg` files directly anyways (and prompts for the password).

Comment: Righty-ho. It might be that encryption uses some stream stuff that requires the input to be unmodified during the process, but decryption doesn't. However if it reliably produces corrupt output, I'd report it as a bug, just in case.

Comment: okay, I'll do that. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

GPG is writing to the same file it's reading from (no temp files).   As it reads plaintext to encrypt, that data is being clobbered by the already-encrypted data GPG is writing out (or vice versa on decryption).  In general, this won't work (it's like a filter that is modifying its input with its output).